# How To Show Total Count

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using `Arcgis API 4.10` where i want to show the total number of count.

Let's suppose I have a Map Server service `http://example.com:yyyy/somepath//MapServer/13` of customers so I want to show the total number of customers by using service and relevant field like `Number_of_SUM` of this service. How can I do this?

I get some hint to try this (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-StatisticDefinition.html), but still stuck here.

Comment: Please provide a code example, preferably using codepen or something similar. It is unclear if you need to create the sum function yourself or if you just want to display an already calculated sum field. It's also unclear where you want to show the count. Please attempt rewriting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a [response from the API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm) through an endpoint like `http://example.com:yyyy/somepath//MapServer/13/query` you can do `response.features.length` to get the length of the feature array.

NOTE: this array is capped by the MapService's "maximum features returned" configuration. I believe the default is 1000 features.